# Passar CSS para o pai partindo do filho

Tags: css

Em CSS consigo passar um CSS para uma div filha, assim:

```css
.pai > .filho{
  color: #ef0a0a;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  pai azul
  <div class="filho">
    filho vermelho
  </div>
</div>
```

Mas como fazer o contrário? Queria saber se é possível e permitido passar um CSS para o o pai, partindo do filho, algo mais ou menos assim:

```css
.filho < .pai{
  color: #0e0aef;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  pai azul
  <div class="filho">
    filho vermelho
  </div>
</div>
```

Da forma que testei não funciona, mas existe alguma forma?

Answer (score -1):

Com CSS existe o seletor :has.

```
.pai:has(> .filho) { color: #0e0aef; }
```

Também é possível com JQuery.

```
$(".filho").parents('.pai').css("color", "#0e0aef");
```